# Instruments Leaks shows non-existent method call

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, memory-leaks

Either I don't understand the Instruments Leaks tool at all, or I am going mad. I have run the tool on my iphone app, and it shows a couple of leaks. If I understand it correctly, for one of the leaks, it says that it is an NSDate object allocated by my method "writeHeading". The method that allocates the object is: "dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:". However, my writeHeading method does not use that method. In fact, that method is not used anywhere in my whole application.

Does anybody have an idea what could be going on here?

Here is the code of writeHeading:

```
- (void) writeHeading:(CLHeading *)heading
{
    if (self.inFlight) {
        [log writeHeading:heading];
    } else {
        IGC_Event *event = [[IGC_Event alloc] init];
        event.code = 'K';
        event.timestamp = heading.timestamp;    
        event.heading = heading;
        [self addEvent:event];
        [event release];
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of Instruments:
[image]

And here is the definition of IGC_Event (as asked by multiple responders):

```
@interface IGC_Event : NSObject {
    int code;
    CLLocation *location;
    CLHeading *heading;
    NSString *other;
    NSDate *timestamp;
}

@property int code;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocation *location;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLHeading *heading;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *other;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *timestamp;

@end


@implementation IGC_Event

@synthesize code;
@synthesize location;
@synthesize heading;
@synthesize other;
@synthesize timestamp;

@end
```

Comment: Does IGC_Event release the timestamp and heading in its dealloc method?

Comment: It should. IGC_Event timestamp is just property with synthesized getters and setters. I'll add the definition of IGC_Event in the question to make that clear

Comment: OK, but are you releasing them in the dealloc? Can you include the dealloc method please?

Comment: The full definition is shown in the question now. A dealloc method with the proper release calls should be generated by the @synthesize directives. Do you think I should add an empty dealloc?

Comment: no, the dealloc method is not generated by @synthesize. So there is your leak (actually 4 potential leaks). I'll add that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no ARC, you need to make sure IGC_Event objects release their timestamp and other references that may have been retained or copied.

So in IGC_Event you need a dealloc something like this:

```
- (void) dealloc {

    [timestamp release];
    [location release];
    [heading release];
    [other release];


    [super dealloc];
}
```

Leaks is just telling you where that timestamp object was created, not where you should have released it.

That may not be the only place you are leaking of course, but that's 4 potential leaks right there.

Comment: Darn, you are fully right of course. In my mind, I have mixed up the new automatic retain management of XCode 4 with the old method. As I have not switched to the new method yet, I should do my own releases. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

When the compiler runs your code, there are the methods directly called by you (which in your screenshot have a little person next to them) and then the methods that are invoked in the core frameworks as a result. The method in question results from this piece of code:

```
event.timestamp = heading.timestamp;
```

You could manage this process yourself if you wanted to:

```
NSDate *eventTimestamp = heading.timestamp;
event.timestamp = eventTimestamp;
```

Incidentally, storing that timestamp is entirely redundant and uses unnecessary memory, since you also store the heading with all its properties in event.heading so at any time you can access that timestamp with `event.heading.timestamp`. However, you may have other reasons for storing it separately.

Comment: Thanks. I have rewritten it the way you show, and now the dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate is indicated on the first of your two lines. Do you have an idea where the dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate call could come from?
I know storing the timestamp is duplication, but it is just easier this way: the IGC_Event can also store other objects besides CLHeading, which may not have timestamps themselves.

Comment: Guessing, but probably either this is called every time an NSDate object is copied, or that a CLHeading timestamp is not an NSDate object but rather a date type that can be assigned to one but requires these method calls under the hood to achieve it. Either way, it is an implementation detail you can safely ignore. :)

Comment: I guess you're right. Maybe the CLHeading timestamp getter is inlined by the compiler, or something. So I guess I need to concentrate on what I do with the timestamp that makes it leak.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the implementation of the `IGC_Event` class? Is it possible that the setter for its `timestamp` property is calling `dateWithTimeIntevalSinceReferenceDate:`? (Not an unreasonable thing to do, so far as I can tell. That would ensure that its timestamp is of class `NSDate` itself, and not a subclass. It would also ensure that it's independent of the timestamp that was passed in.)

(Disclaimer: I'm *really* not much of an Objective-C-er. If this seems like a stupid question, then it probably is!)

Comment: That is certainly not a stupid question, and it might have been the issue, if the IGC_Event was defined that way. But the timestamp in IGC_Event is just an @property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *timestamp, with synthesized setters and getters. No special stuff there.